# Get a square matrix out of a non symetric data frame

Tags: r

I'm a total beginner in R. I have a series of data relating the surnames of married persons.

```
    Id_mar  Wife  Husband
1      1    Smith Johnson
2      2    Smith  Carter
3      3    White  Carter
4      4    Wang   Smith
5      5    White  Carter
```

I need to get it under the form of a square matrix (in order to be able to manipulate it in various ways).
So I suppose I have to first cast it:

```
data.melt<-melt(dat.mar,id=c('Wife','Husband'))
dat.melt$value<-1    
dat.cast<-cast(dat.melt, Wife~Husband, length)

       Wife Carter Johnson Smith
    1 Smith      1       1     0
    2  Wang      0       0     1
    3 White      2       0     0
```

And then transform it into a matrix:

```
dat.mat<-as.matrix(dat.cast)
      Carter Johnson Smith
Smith      1       1     0
Wang       0       0     1
White      2       0     0
```

But now, how do I accurately add columns and rows so that I get a square matrix with the rows and columns in the correct alphabetic order? Something looking like this:

```
      Carter Johnson Smith    Wang   White
Carter     0       0     0       0       0
Johnson    0       0     0       0       0
Smith      1       1     0       0       0
Wang       0       0     1       0       0
White      2       0     0       0       0
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you could shorten your whole process to just `table(dat.mar[-1])`

Comment: `melt()` is not in `{base}`. From which package it is?

Comment: Thanks David. That's the beginning of the answer; see below

Comment: melt is part of the reshape package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the expected output, we can use `table` (as @David Arenburg mentioned in the comments) on `factor` converted 'Wife' and 'Husband' columns, specifying the `levels` as the `sort`ed `unique` elements of both the columns ('Un1')

```
 Un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(df1[-1])))
 table(factor(df1$Wife, levels=Un1), factor(df1$Husband, levels=Un1))
 #          Carter Johnson Smith Wang White
 # Carter       0       0     0    0     0
 # Johnson      0       0     0    0     0
 # Smith        1       1     0    0     0
 # Wang         0       0     1    0     0
 # White        2       0     0    0     0
```

---

Or we can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`.

```
 library(qdapTools)
 mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1])))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Akrun. It works and it's so fast! What if I want the same in alphabetical order, for easy reference (in reality I have two dozen columns)?

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez  If you noticed, I did the `sort` which sorts by alphabetical order.

Comment: I could get a fine square matrix, but with the columns in this order: Smith, Wang, White, Carter, Johnson. And that's what the first sort command returns.
+what you name as df1 is my original data frame right? The one on the very top of my message?

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez  If you need a custom order specify that as the levels, ie. `Un1 <- c('Smith', 'Wang', 'White', 'Carter', 'Johnson')` and then `table(factor(df1$Wife, levels=Un1), factor(df1$Husband ,levels=Un1))`  Yes, I named `df1` as it is simple to use and reduce the typing for me.

Comment: A problem appears if I have an additional column in the data frame, which I want to keep, with for example "age". It will be added in the table.

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez  In that case, subset out that column and then do the `mtabulate`

Comment: It works! Seems I forgot the basics. Thank you Akrun. Nice day!