# convert R data frame to wide format with presence/absence call as value

Tags: r, transpose

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
ID  cat1  cat2  cat3
1  cat1_A  cat2_A  cat3_A
2  cat1_B  cat2_A  cat3_B
3  cat1_B  cat2_B  cat3_A
```

I would now like to convert this to a kind of transposed table using all values in each column as new column names, and a 0/1 (presence/absence) call for the respective column name as new value:

```
ID cat1_A cat1_B cat2_A cat2_B cat3_A cat3_B
1 1 0 1 0 1 0
2 0 1 1 0 0 1
3 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

I hope it's clear what I'd like to do, not sure how to explain it in a better way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a square matrix out of a non symetric data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480407/get-a-square-matrix-out-of-a-non-symetric-data-frame) Or you can also use [Convert row values into columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713760/convert-row-values-into-columns-in-r/) with little modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
res <- cbind(df1[1], mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1]))))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#   ID cat1_A cat2_A cat3_A cat1_B cat3_B cat2_B
#1  1      1      1      1      0      0      0
#2  2      0      1      0      1      1      0
#3  3      0      0      1      1      0      1
```